# HttpRequest blocked mixed content

Tags: reactjs

```
 BASE_URL = "http://********:8091/api/v1";
```

I have uploaded my react-js application on netlify.com. in react js I implemented APIs.... when I hit APIs  after deploying I got this error on console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xyz.netlify.app/' was loaded over
> HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
> 'http://*******:8091/api/v1/categories/'. This request has been
> blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

what is the solution to this

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no solution. This is how the common browsers designed. You have to request API server over HTTPS, or just disable HTTPS at frontend. Happy to help!

Comment: `BASE_URL = "https://********:8091/api/v1";` Change the protocol to `https`

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, There's no way to disable mixed content**

Just Add the Below meta tag to your HTML file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```